# Mono - Issue with binary operator between two different types

Tags: c#, mono, operator-overloading

Good day. I'm implementing the Complex class in C# with Mono under Ububntu 14.04. I have found some strange behaviors when I tied to implement the multiplication between a double and a Complex.
My Complex implementation is something like

```
using System;

namespace Mynamespace {
public class Complex {
public double re;//Real part
public double im;//Imaginary part


public Complex (double a, double b){
re = a;
im = b;
}

public static Complex operator *(double k, Complex x){
return new Complex (k * x.re, k * x.im);
}
}}
```

The test code is like

```
...
Complex a = new Complex (1, 1);
double b = 2.0;
Complex c = b * a;
...
```

The strange behavior is that the operator * returns the wrong result. I noticed that when * is called the argument of type double has the wrong value within the function (I pass b = 2 and I see that the argument k has a random value).

I have also tried to implement the function without using operators:

```
...
public Complex Multiply(double k){
return new Complex (k * re, k * im)
}
...
```

and also

```
...
public static Complex Multiply (double k, Complex x){
return new Complex (k * x.re, k * x.im)
}
...
```

but I obtain alwais the same behavior.
I have tried it under C# in .net (Windows7) and everything works perfectly.

Does anybody have any suggestion on how to fix it?

Best regards

Federico

Comment: You have to supply code that reproduces your behaviour. I don't have Mono, but I'm pretty sure this doesn't (someone would notice if passing `double`s didn't work). Also, it's obviously not about the operator overloading when you can reproduce it with a static method. Also, note that it's *extremely* unlikely for the passed value to have a *random* value - both the stack and the heap are pre-zeroed, so even if you somehow referenced an unitialized value, it would pretty likely be zero, rather than "random". Are you perhaps using the multiplication in an anonymous method with a closure?

Comment: The code I reported produces the issue I described. Indeed, the value actually passed to the multiplication function is not random, but it's not the value I meant to pass. The very strange think is that the same code in Visual Studio C# gives right results.

Comment: What version of Mono? I tested this with MonoDevelop 5.7 (Mono 3.12.1) and it works exactly as expected. The behavior you're describing is such a basic defect in a well-exercised part of the language and run-time that IMHO the only plausible explanations are that either you have a corrupted install of Mono or related software, or that you are misinterpreting your observations and that the code you are using doesn't look exactly like what you've posted here.

Comment: I have tried it in MonoDevelop 5.7 ad well. The code is exactly the dame ad reported. If I try to overload binary operator * between two Complex everything works well. The only strage behavior arises when I use operators between double and Complex. I will try to reinstall everything. Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using? Does this happen on Windows as well? Do you have an implicit cast operator overload for your `Complex` class? This is incredibly suspicious. Perhaps you should make a bug report to the Mono team?

Comment: I'm using MonoDevelop 5.7 under Ubuntu 14.04 lts. I tried also to download a library with Matrix class already implemented and again I found the same problem with multiplication between double an Matrix. I haven't tried to reinstall Mono yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with something like

```
public static Complex operator *(object k, complex x){
return new ((double)k * x.re, (double)k * x.im);
}
```

Now everything works well. If you have any suggestion for understanding the problem I had, they are all welcomed.

Best regards

Federico

Comment: I found that the problem arises only during debug, while in normal execution everything goes normal.